# Python Nested list function to return score for students exam's.

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, average

I am trying to write a function named studentGrades(gradeList) that takes a nested list and returns a list with the average score for each student. 
An example would be:

```
 grades= [['Student','Quiz 1','Quiz 2','Quiz 3','Final'],
 ['John', 100, 90, 80, 90],
 ['McVay', 88, 99, 11, 15],
 ['Rita', 45, 56, 67, 89],
 ['Ketan', 59, 61, 67, 32],
 ['Saranya', 73, 79, 83, 45],
 ['Min', 89, 97, 101, 100]]
 studentGrades(grades)

 # Sample output below
 >>> [90, 53, 64, 54, 70, 96]
```

I don't know how to do this using a nested loop. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: is that input given? this would be cleaner if you use a dictionary for grades

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: @Banana It was just a example. I don't know what the input will be the tested input.

Comment: @jacobostrowski but the input is always of that exact same structure, yes?

Comment: What attempt have you made?

Answer (score 1):

Incase you need a one liner

```
[int(sum(i[1:])/len(i[1:])) for i in grades[1:]]
```

Output:

```
[90, 53, 64, 54, 70, 96]
```

Comment: Why truncate instead of proper rounding?

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Thought so. But OP's sample output has elements truncated

Comment: `len(i[1:]) == len(i) - 1`. No need to compute the sublist twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def studentGrades(a):
    # return [sum(k[1:])/(len(k)-1) for k in a[1:]]
    # Or
    l = len(a[0]) - 1 # how many quizzes, thanks to @Mad Physicist
    return [sum(k[1:])/l for k in a[1:]]

grades= [['Student','Quiz 1','Quiz 2','Quiz 3','Final'],
 ['John', 100, 90, 80, 90],
 ['McVay', 88, 99, 11, 15],
 ['Rita', 45, 56, 67, 89],
 ['Ketan', 59, 61, 67, 32],
 ['Saranya', 73, 79, 83, 45],
 ['Min', 89, 97, 101, 100]]

final = studentGrades(grades)
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[90, 53, 64, 54, 70, 96]
```

Comment: `len(a[0][1:]) == len(a[0]) - 1`. Seems overkill to make a separate sublist just for that...

Comment: Also, you should probably incorporate that into the loop, in case a student missed a quiz or something.

Comment: @MadPhysicist good point for the length. And i really hesitated before posting the answer ... I think it's a part of the OP homework, but still i didn't know if it's or not. I'm updating my answer. thanks for your comment

Comment: The answer is fine, and thanks for acknowledging that it is best not to enable lazy OPs like this. Homework is not the issue here. Asking for free code with zero demonstrated effort is.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in the comments, you can also use a dictionary for that. Dictionaries are basically made for situations like these and if you want to use your data any further, they might prove beneficial.
You would first have to convert your current structure, which I assumed is fixed in the sense that you have a "header" in grades, and then lists of the form [name,points..]. You can do:

```
grades= [['Student','Quiz 1','Quiz 2','Quiz 3','Final'],
 ['John', 100, 90, 80, 90],
 ['McVay', 88, 99, 11, 15],
 ['Rita', 45, 56, 67, 89],
 ['Ketan', 59, 61, 67, 32],
 ['Saranya', 73, 79, 83, 45],
 ['Min', 89, 97, 101, 100]]
gradedict = {}
for rows in grades[1:]:
    gradedict[rows[0]] = rows[1:]
```

To initialize the dictionary. Then the following function:

```
def studentGrades(gradedict):
    avgdict = {}
    for key,lst in gradedict.items():
        avgdict[key] = sum(lst)/len(lst) 
    return avgdict
```

Returns another dictionary with the corresponding averages. You could loop through the names, i.e. the keys, of either of those to print that. For example:

```
gradedict = studentGrades(gradedict)
for x in gradedict:
    print("student ",x, " achieved an average of: ",gradedict[x])
```

which is just to show you how to access the elements. you can of course also loop through keys,items as I did in the function.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use pandas?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(grades).set_index(0).iloc[1:].mean(axis=1).astype(int)
```

**Output:**

```
John       90
McVay      53
Rita       64
Ketan      54
Saranya    70
Min        96
```

or

```
list(df.values)
```

**Output:**

```
[90, 53, 64, 54, 70, 96]
```

Comment: OP seems to have mentioned that they are at a stage where they are trying to learn very basic constructs like loops. That's a long way away from being able to understand the language well enough to quickly grasp what a complex series of library calls is doing. While this answer is quite elegant, it is not useful in context of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
grades= [['Student','Quiz 1','Quiz 2','Quiz 3','Final'],
 ['John', 100, 90, 80, 90],
 ['McVay', 88, 99, 11, 15],
 ['Rita', 45, 56, 67, 89],
 ['Ketan', 59, 61, 67, 32],
 ['Saranya', 73, 79, 83, 45],
 ['Min', 89, 97, 101, 100]]

def average(grades):
    for m in grades[1:]:
        t = m[1:]
        l = len(t)
        s = sum(t)
        yield s//l

list(average(grades))
```